# can we change Kendo Tree Transport Read URL after initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have initialized tree in kendo UI.

```
 $("#ID").kendoTreeView({

        dataSource: {
            type: "json",

            transport: {
                read:
                    {
                        url: Old URL 
                    }

            } //transport
        } //datasource
    });
```

After Init I have changed its URL of transport.

```
TreeView.dataSource.options.transport.read.url=NewURL
TreeView.dataSource.read()
```

But after changing  url its taking data from new url  for first node only rest of child node is fetched from old URL.
please share idea for solution.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the loadOnDemand config option to false. Setting this to false causes all child DataSources to be loaded at initialization time.

```
$("#ID").kendoTreeView({
        loadOnDemand: false,
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",

            transport: {
                read:
                    {
                        url: Old URL 
                    }

            } //transport
        } //datasource
    });
```